# Can't install the android studio package

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu

I just got an old windows 7 pc, I turn it into an ubuntu 16.04 LTS in order to give this old boy a second more usefull life^^

I was trying to install the android studio package, but I have an issue I can't fix when i'm trying

`sudo apt install android-studio`

I'm getting

> Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
>   Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
>
> Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
>   Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
>     android-studio
>   0 mis à jour, 1 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 4 non mis à jour.
>   Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/40,4 ko dans les archives.
>
> Après cette opération, 80,9 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
>   (Lecture de la base de données... 220611 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
>
> Préparation du dépaquetage de .../android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb ...
>   --2018-01-09 14:26:57--  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.1.0.9/android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip
>   Résolution de dl.google.com (dl.google.com)… 216.58.204.238, 2a00:1450:4007:816::200e
>
> **Connexion à dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.204.238|:443… connecté.
>   requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 404 Not Found
>   2018-01-09 14:26:57 erreur 404 : Not Found.**
>
> dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb (--unpack) :
>    le sous-processus nouveau script pre-installation a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 8
>
> Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Sorry for the french inside, but basiclly, looks like he can't connect to google that's why I get a 404 error (bold block, all is fine before) , and that's why the the script is failing later i guess.

Have you any solution ? Thanks guys.

EDIT: Here is a google translate

> Reading Package Lists ... Done Building the Dependency Tree
>
> Reading status information ... Done The following NEW packages will be
>   installed: android-studio 0 updated, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 4 not updated. It is necessary to take 0 o / 40.4 ko in the
>   archive.
>
> After this operation, 80.9 KB of additional disk space will be used.
>   (Reading the database ... 220611 files and directories already
>   installed.)
>
> Preparing unpacking of ... / android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb ...
>   --2018-01-09 14: 26: 57-- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ ide-zips / 2.1.0.9 / android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip
>   dl.google.com (dl.google.com) Resolution ... 216.58.204.238, 2a00:
>   1450: 4007: 816 :: 200th
>
> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com) | 216.58.204.238 |: 443
>   ... connected. HTTP request transmitted, waiting for response ... 404
>   Not Found 2018-01-09 14:26:57 error 404: Not Found.
>
> dpkg: archive processing error
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb
>   (--unpack): the new pre-installation script sub-process returned an
>   exit error of state 8
>
> Errors were encountered during execution:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb E:
>   Subprocess / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Just in case. Languge in linux is stored in `$LANG` environment variable. If you want to display error message in English you can do something like this: `LANG_TMP=$LANG; LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, execute your command and then return to previous language by using `LANG=$LANG_TMP`. Mind spaces and dollar signs. I've struggled with them a little bit when I wrote my first bash lines.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see android studio in [ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) (with apt `apt search android-studio`, synaptic or other methods). When I installed it I went to [google's download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and then followed [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) to get android studio up and running.

Comment: Those instructions are made for windows so this isn't really what I need here. Concerning the google download, I agreee, that's why there is this line `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ ide-zips / 2.1.0.9 / android-studio-ide-143.2790544-linux.zip dl.google.com ` but he can't find the zip. And the link you are first referring to is made for winows too, so that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: You have to choose linux instructions from a dropdown. **EDIT** or if you are talking about download options scroll down to download options: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: Ok I get it; I got more than 1 hour for downloading the zip I guess this is why it's failing in command line, my current connection is just too bad.

Answer (score -1):

`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. It is one of the common issue in Ubuntu and other DEB-based systems.

This usually happens due to a failed application installation, or if the dpkg package installer becomes corrupted or interrupted in mid-way while installing a package.

**Solution 1 - Reconfigure dpkg database**

If the package installation process is stopped or interrupted in mid-way, the dpkg database might be corrupted. Reconfiguring dpkg database may solve this issue.

To reconfigure dpkg database, simply run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**olution 2 - Force install the application**

If the first method didn't work, run the following command to perform force install:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

**Solution 3 - Remove the problematic application .deb file from the local cache folder and reinstall it**

As you see in the error message (the last two lines), the eog package is causing this error.

```
[...]
/var/cache/apt/archives/eog_3.36.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For those wondering, eog (short for Eye of GNOME) is the official and default image viewer for the GNOME desktop environment. So this package is problematic and doesn't let me to upgrade my Ubuntu.

When you install a package, it will be downloaded and saved in the cache folder /var/cache/apt/archives/.

To fix this error, remove the cached package using command:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/eog_3.36.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Replace eog_3.36.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb with your package.

Clean the package cache folder:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Update the source lists:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

Upgrade your system:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally, get the fresh package from official repositories and reinstall it like below:

```
sudo apt-get install eog
```

**Solution 4 - Remove the problematic application**

This should be your last resort. If none of the above methods help, remove the problematic package from your system like below:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge eog
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command will remove eog with all its configuration files from the system.

And also find and remove all files associated with the broken package.

To find all files related to a package, run:

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i eog
```

Sample output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 61926 Apr 24 13:42 eog.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5889 Mar 29 08:01 eog.md5sums
```

Remove them manually.

That's it. At this stage, any one of the these four solutions should have helped you to fix "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" in Ubuntu and other DEB-based systems.

### For more detailed explanations, I suggest you read this article:

**Reference:**

https://ostechnix.com/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-in-ubuntu/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)